# absolute convergence of infinite product

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

We know if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|z_n|$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n$ converges absolutely. (kind of trivial)

I wonder whether it holds for infinite products, that is,
if $\prod_{n=1}^\infty|z_n|$ converges then $\prod_{n=1}^\infty z_n$ converges absolutely.

Is the statement above true or not?

Thanks a lot!

I know $\prod_{n=1}^\infty|z_n|$ converges doesn't imply $\prod_{n=1}^\infty z_n$ converges.

Comment: First line, second sum: take off the absolute value. And no: it's not a trivial claim.

Comment: Did you mean the statement is false? Is there any counterexample?

Comment: @DonAntonio, can you please have look at another post? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699928/convergence-of-two-complex-series

Comment: @DonAntonio, thank you very much!

Comment: No, the statement just doesn't make much sense as it is: it should be, imo: if the series $\;\sum |z_n|\;$ converges then so does the series $\;\sum z_n\;$ , and then we say this last one converges absolutely. The claim is the first part above, and its proof is not trivial (though it isn't hard, either)

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: Either you've already proved your first line and *really* found the proof "trivial", or else you still haven't and you should then delete that "trivial" comment...And about your question: I'm not sure right now.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $z_n=-1$, so that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty |z_n|$ trivially converges to $1$. But $z_n=1+(-2)$, and the definition of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+(-2))$ converging absolutely is that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+|{-}2|) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty 3$ converges, which it does not.

Comment: I'm not sure why this makes sense. $|1+(-2)|\neq |1|+|-2|$. It would be better to say that $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N} -1$ does not converge since it oscillates.

Comment: $\Re z_n$ should be positive according to the definition of absolute convergence.

Comment: The definition of $\prod y_n$ converging absolutely is *not* that $\prod|y_n|$ converges; rather, it is that $\prod(1+|y_n-1|)$ converges. A necessary condition is that $y_n$ tends to $1$, which means that one may assume that $\Re y_n$ is positive if one wishes.